# Fit data with a given function depending on parameters

Tags: fitting, data, modeling

I want to fit the data of a star's temperature with a function from a model. That function depend on several parameters. I want to know how can I find the value of those parameters.

The data is:

```
CasA = {{333, 6.3258}, {335, 6.3237}, {337, 6.317}, {340, 6.3127}, {342, 6.3104}}
```

The function that I'm using is:

```
Temperature[t_] := Tc/(1 + (t - tc) f/tc)
```

In the literature there are values for the parameters Tc and tc, however I want to find them using a fitting.

I have been trying changing the parameters by hand, but that looks like a very silly way to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Best,
JD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the FindFit function like this

FindFit[casA, temperature[t], {Tc, tc, f}, t]

It gives the result

{Tc -> 6.84314, tc -> 69.678, f -> 0.0216365}

By the way, it is good practice to name your variables with initial lower case.